# graph line (X,Y,Z) control

Tags: c#, winforms, graph, line

Hello I am searching for a graph that will allow me to make Z Line Graph control now I have X (Payment_Date) & Y (collected) line how to make Z (username) line
I want every username to have his line alone

Can someone help me?

I want to make the program on normal C# win form application

My Form 
[image: My Form]

```
SqlDataReader reader = sqlcomm.ExecuteReader();
                    DataTable sd = new DataTable();
                    sd.Load(reader);
                    dataGridView1.DataSource = sd;
                    reader.Close();



                    chart1.Series["collected"].XValueMember = "Payment_Date";
                    chart1.Series["collected"].XValueType = System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartValueType.Date;
                    chart1.Series["collected"].YValueMembers = "collected";
                    chart1.Series["collected"].YValueType = System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartValueType.Int32;
                    chart1.DataSource = sd;
                    chart1.DataBind();
```

[image]

Comment: The question isn't really clear. If you want to add a Series for each user do it! If you want to show only one of those series simply disable the others. As it stands the question seems to aim at a 3D graph but I'm guessing that it doesn't really?!? - (MSChart can do it but not very well. You still may want to look into it. The 'Z-Axis' is simulated by - adding more series..) [Examples](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A3152130+chart+3d)

Comment: Also: You will have to fix the binding. You probably will have to create one or more DataSources that filter for only one user each. Then bind it to the Points of one series only, not the whole chart!

Comment: @TaW in your second answer I have something like that and it works good but when I try to see all user it looks like that one series . can you help me to show me what should I have to add to my code to have series for every user alone when in this example and I will try to continue on it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step one: Create a separate `BindingSource` for each element you want to bind and set an appropriate `Filter` so it will only display the data of one user each.

Step two: Show and hide the Series you want to.

I have created a `DataTable dt` with 3 columns:

```
dt.Columns.Add("User", typeof(string));
dt.Columns.Add("Date", typeof(DateTime));
dt.Columns.Add("Value", typeof(double));
```

and filled it randomly. Next I pull out the **distinct** users:

```
var users = dt.Rows.Cast<DataRow>()
                  .Select(x => x.Field<string>("User"))
                  .Distinct()
                  .OrderBy(x => x)
                  .ToList();
```

Most likely you will reverse this and start with a list of users.

Now I create a `Series` with its own filtered `BindingSource`  for each user:

```
for (int i = 0; i < users.Count; i++)
{
    Series s = chart1.Series.Add(users[i]);
    s.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line;
    BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
    bs.DataSource = dt;
    bs.Filter = "User='" + users[i] + "'";
    s.Points.DataBindXY(bs, "Date", bs, "Value");
}
```

Now I bind my DGV:

```
BindingSource bsdgv = new BindingSource();
bsdgv.DataSource = dt;
bsdgv.Filter = "";
dataGridView1.DataSource = bsdgv;
```

I have hidden the `Series` by making them `Transparent`. This way the names still show in the Legend. The trick is to keep the original colors in the Series' `Tags`..:

```
void hideAllSeries(Chart chart)
{
    chart.ApplyPaletteColors();
    foreach (Series s in chart.Series)
    {
        if (s.Color != Color.Transparent) s.Tag = s.Color;
        s.Color = Color.Transparent;
    }
}
```

To show or hide a `Series` I code the `MouseClick` event:

```
private void Chart1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    var hitt = chart1.HitTest(e.X, e.Y);
    if (hitt.ChartElementType == ChartElementType.LegendItem)
    {
        Series s = hitt.Series;
        if (s.Color == Color.Transparent)
        {
            s.Color = (Color)s.Tag;
        }
        else
        {
            s.Tag = s.Color;
            s.Color = Color.Transparent;
        }
    }
}
```

Let's see it at work:

[image]

Instead of this solution you may want to add a User selection Checklist and set the DGV's BindingSource's Filter..

Comment: plz how to add something like this `Chart1.Series["Default"].BorderWidth = 10;`

Comment: Explan what you want to do: Add a new Sereis? Also a Line? BorderWidth will indeed set the  Linewidth, albeit a bit thick. Where is the problem?

Comment: there is no problem and thank you again I try `chart1.Series[i].BorderWidth = 5;` and it work